# Chebychev polynomial nodes on a triangle

Tags: calculus, polynomials, approximation, interpolation, change-of-variable

I am trying to find the [Chebychev approximation nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_nodes) on a triangle (or tetrahedron) with arbitrary edge lengths.

For example

Suppose I have a $D$-variate function, $f(x_{1},...,x_{D})$, with range in $\mathbb{R}^1$.

The domain of $f$ is a tetrahedron, with constraints as follows:

$x_{1}+x_{2}\leq a_1$

$x_{3}+x_{4}\leq a_2$

$\vdots$

$x_{D-1}+x_{D}\leq a_D$

and

$x_i\geq 0 \;\forall \; i={1,...,D}$

(Alternatively a simpler tetrahedron I'd also be interested in would be $\sum_{i=1}^Dx_{i}<a$)

For example, suppose $D=2$ and $a_{1}=25$, how would I find the Chebychev nodes on this space below?

[image]

The chebychev nodes on the full rectangle are:

[Rectangle chebychev nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIKag.jpg)

As you can see, the edges are oversampled to minimize approximation error.  If I now just take the domain restrictions, we end up with seemingly too few points along the hypotenuse!

[triangle nodes, incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7YGo.jpg)

Comment: Perhaps people who downvote could explain how to improve the question?

Comment: I didn't down vote but, to me, a Chebyhshev polynomial is a specific polynomial in one variable, and the Chebyshev nodes are its roots. Before I could answer this question, I would need to know what you mean by a Chebyshev polynomial on a higher dimensional space, and what you mean by its nodes.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer  Hi, you can have use polynomial interpolation for multivariate functions.  For example, $z = f(x,y)$  can be approximated with a $N=2$ degree polynomial with $z = b_0 + b_1x + b_2y + b_3xy + b_4x^2 + b_5y^2 + b_6x^2y^2$.  You can then use chebychev nodes over the (x,y) domain, but here it is a triangle instead of a rectangle.  I will post some more pictures in a moment.

Comment: Re the above, but instead of using x, y, x^2, use the chebychev versions of these polynomials

Comment: how do you measure how good a particular set of nodes would be ?

Comment: Hi @mercio, I am not a mathematician in approximation theory, but us the chebychev minimax property and the polynomials.  (Powell 1981, pg 78, thm 7.3) and Rivlin (1990 pg 14)

Comment: @mercio however, I think it is simple enough to map the rectangle to the triangle, I don't think you need to worry about much beyond that.  The wiki article gives the formula for the chebychev nodes on [-1,1] for M points.  Then it gives the formula to map this space to an arbitrary interval [a,b]